# Access MainWindow namespace from another project in a different namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, namespaces

I have a solution with a number of projects, each with a different namespace.  I am trying access the MainWindow status bar control from a process launched in one of the other projects. The other projects are all launched from a ribbon in the MainWindow project and therefore there are references to each of the other projects in the MainWindow project.  I cannot add a reference to my MainWindow project in the other projects because it creates a circular dependency.  Therefore the other projects do not know anything about the existence of the MainWindow namespace.  I have found a number of examples but they all show the different classes in the same project and namespace so they know about the MainWindow.

Comment: If they are launched from different processes it will be hard, if they are just windows inside the process you can make a public static reference to that mainwindow.

Comment: I have tried that but the "child" project does not know anything about the parent project containing the MainWindow.  Beginning to think that the child projects cannot use anything from the StartUp project.  If this is so then the StatusBar in a main window seems to have limited use in a complex solution.

Comment: You should launch those child projects as new windows but still on the same process so they could communicate between each other.